# Why am I getting an Infinite loop when validating my user input?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm trying to validate the user inputs. If the user inputs anything but an integer it should stay in the `While` loop. But when I give the program a "w" for instance the program just endlessly prints "Please input integer" and I have to stop the program.

```
int MAns1 = 0
while (!(cin >> MAns1))
{
    cout << "\nPlease Enter An Integer: ";
    cin.clear();
}
```

Comment: This is totally duplicate. My Bad. Also I figured it out:

while (!(cin >> MAns1))
   {
    cout << "\nPlease Enter An Integer: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
   }

Answer (score 0):

Because you should be testing `(cin >> MAns1)`, not `!(cin >> MAns1)`. I would do something like this though:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main() { 
    int MAns1 = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease Enter An Integer: ";
        cin >> MAnsi;

        // did the last read succeed?
        if(!cin) {
          // it did *not* succeed.
          break;
        }
    }
}
```